# Multiple Input Models with any one required field validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Multiple Input models with any one required field validation should be there , below mentioned a sample , please help to resolve it . Below i have three input field , out of any on these three one should be required .

```
   public class search
{
    public string Sample1 { get; set; }
    public string Sample2 { get; set; }
    public string Sample3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And what the problem?

Comment: Start reading about model validation and data annotations.

Comment: You need to specify more information about what kind of project this class is being used in order for us to help you. For instance is it an ASP.NET project? How are you receiving this input? Etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class search : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Sample1 { get; set; }
    public string Sample2 { get; set; }
    public string Sample3 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
    { 
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sample1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sample2) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sample3))
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Required."));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IValidatableObject`

```
public class search : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Sample1 { get; set; }
    public string Sample2 { get; set; }
    public string Sample3 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
    { 
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sample1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sample2) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sample3))
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("One of them is required."));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have sent the json for the input as null or empty, not throwing error .

Comment: Passing value also throwing error .{
  "Sample1": null,
  "Sample2": null,
  "Sample3": "test"
}

Comment: My bad, it should be "and" instead of "or"